# PrototypeJS/Javascript - How to update various attributes in a Ajax Request?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I've a Prototype code that handles voting. I click in the arrows, and the JavaScript/Prototype codes handles it correctly.

My problem now is that I've a site with Tabs, and the same voting form for the same article could show twice or more in the same page. Since the script work with ID's I have a problem.

My question is on how can I modify this code to handle the same voting form for the same article could more than one time in the same page? Basically I need to update the attributes for all the forms.

The Prototype code:

```
//
// The VoteHijacker JS
//


var VoteHijacker = Class.create();
VoteHijacker.prototype =
{
    initialize: function(prefix)
    {
    console.log('this.prefix:' + this.prefix + ' prefix:' + prefix);
        this.prefix = prefix || "";
        this.registerEventHandlers();
    },

    registerEventHandlers: function()
    {
        $$("form." + this.prefix + "vote").each(function(form)
        {
            Event.observe(form, "submit", this.doVote.bindAsEventListener(this), false);
        }.bind(this));
    },

    doVote: function(e)
    {
        Event.stop(e);
        var form = Event.element(e);
        var id = /(\d+)$/.exec(form.id)[1];
        var action = /(up|down|clear)vote/.exec(form.action)[1];
        new Ajax.Request(form.action, {
            onComplete: VoteHijacker.processVoteResponse(this.prefix, id, action)
        });
    }
};

VoteHijacker.processVoteResponse = function(prefix, id, action)
{
    return function(transport)
    {
        var response = transport.responseText.evalJSON();
        if (response.success === true)
        {
            var upArrowType = "grey";
            var upFormAction = "up";
            var downArrowType = "grey";
            var downFormAction = "down";

            if (action == "up")
            {
                var upArrowType = "mod";
                var upFormAction = "clear";
            }
            else if (action == "down")
            {
                var downArrowType = "mod";
                var downFormAction = "clear";
            }

            VoteHijacker.updateArrow("up", prefix, id, upArrowType);
            VoteHijacker.updateArrow("down", prefix, id, downArrowType);
            VoteHijacker.updateFormAction("up", prefix, id, upFormAction);
            VoteHijacker.updateFormAction("down", prefix, id, downFormAction);
            VoteHijacker.updateScore(prefix, id, response.score);

        }
        else
        {
            alert("Erro a votar: " + response.error_message);
        }
    };
};

VoteHijacker.updateArrow = function(arrowType, prefix, id, state)
{
    var img = $(prefix + arrowType + "arrow" + id);
    var re = new RegExp("a" + arrowType + "(?:mod|grey)\\.png");
    img.src = img.src.replace(re, "a" + arrowType + state + ".png");
};

VoteHijacker.updateFormAction = function(formType, prefix, id, action)
{
    var form = $(prefix + formType + id);
    form.action = form.action.replace(/(?:up|down|clear)vote/, action + "vote");
};

VoteHijacker.updateScore = function(prefix, id, score)
{
    var scoreElement = $(prefix + "score" + id);
    scoreElement.innerHTML = score.score /*+ " point" + VoteHijacker.pluralize(score.score)*/;
    scoreElement.title = "after " + score.num_votes + " vote" + VoteHijacker.pluralize(score.num_votes);
};

VoteHijacker.pluralize = function(value)
{
    if (value != 1)
    {
        return "s";
    }
    return "";
};
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="upparrow">
    <form class="mainvote" id="mainup{{ main.id }}" action="/votarem/main/{{ main.id }}/{% if vote and vote.is_upvote %}clear{% else %}up{% endif %}vote?next=/" method="POST">
    <input type="image" id="mainuparrow{{ main.id }}" src="/media/images/aup{% if vote and vote.is_upvote %}mod{% else %}grey{% endif %}.png">
    </form>                             
</div>
<div class="actualvotes">
<span class="score" id="mainscore{{ main.id }}" title="depois de {{ score.num_votes|default:0 }} voto{{ score.num_votes|default:0|pluralize }}">
    {{ score.score|default:0 }}
</span>                                     
</div>
<div class="downarrow">
    <form class="mainvote" id="maindown{{ main.id }}" action="/votarem/main/{{ main.id }}/{% if vote and vote.is_downvote %}clear{% else %}down{% endif %}vote?next=/" method="POST">
        <input type="image" id="maindownarrow{{ main.id }}" src="/media/images/adown{% if vote and vote.is_downvote %}mod{% else %}grey{% endif %}.png">
    </form>                                 
</div>
```

Any clue on what should I do to handle the problem exposed above?

PS: Sorry my english.

Best Regards,

Comment: Ids must not occur multiple times in the same document, point.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can create multiple instances of the `VoteHijacker` class you just need to make sure the form ids are different and the separate instances point to the right form.

I'm guessing that when you create the instance you do so by

```
new VoteHijacker('main');
```

this is easily changeable to point to a different form just make sure the class of the new form matches a different instance invocation and that the form id is unique for instance

add a new set of forms to the page that has a class `tab1` and ids `tab1up{{ main.id }}`,`tab1down{{ main.id}}`